# Deserialize the result dynamically for Protobuf-net.dll

Tags: .net, serialization, silverlight-5.0, protobuf-net

I am playing around with the C# protobuf implementation and I might have run into a problem. I want to deserialize the result dynamically.

```
public byte[] ManageRequest(string argument1, params FunctionalParameter[] argument2)
{
    var serverBase = new ServerBase();

    if (argument1 != null)
    {
        MethodInfo type = serverBase.GetType().GetMethod(argument1);
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = type.GetParameters();

        if (parameters.Length.Equals(argument2.Length))
        {
            var pars = new object[argument2.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                if (parameters[i].Name == argument2[i].ParameterNameField)
                {
                    using (Stream result = new MemoryStream(argument2[i].ParameterValueField))
                    {
                        pars[i] = Serializer.Deserialize<int>(result); // I want to deserialize the //result dynamically( not want to use int, we can pass result dynamically)
                    }
                }
            }

            if (pars.Length.Equals(argument2.Length))
            {
                return type.Invoke(serverBase, pars).ToProtoBuf();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The method takes two arguments:
1. `argument1` - MethodName 
2. `argument2` - Array of `FunctionalParameter`s (In this class we have two members:
`string ParameterNameField` and `byte[] ParameterValueField`.)

I want to Deserialize the result dynamically, e.g `Serializer.Deserialize<int>(result);` I have passed int to serialize, in this case I know that we need to deserialize the result in int type but I want to deserialize the result dynamically that I have serialized.

Using `parameters[i].ParameterType.Name` code I got the class name (e.g `System.Int32`, etc) and user defind datatype, like `Class1`, `Class2`, etc. If I passed `Serializer.Deserialize <parameters[i].GetType()> (result)` in this case I got the following error:

> Cannot apply `operator '<'` to operands of type '`method group`' and '`System.Type`'

`Protobuf.Serializer` is a class in protobuf-net.dll. In this class, `Serialize<T>(System.IO.Stream)` and `Deserialize<T>(System.IO.Stream)` are two methods to serialize and deserialize the result.

I do not understand that how this is possible! Can you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Serializer.Deserialize<T>(...)` API is generic. There is, however, a non-generic API... `Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(...)` that accepts a `Type`. It sounds like you want to use this latter API.

As a side note: in the v1.* builds, the primary API is generic; the non-generic API had to do some extra work (and had some extra overhead). In the v2.* builds, the core codebase is non-generic. The generic API doesn't have additional overhead from this, as it can just use `typeof(T)` etc.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks.. 
Using this, I got the result that I have want ... I wrote some code that Deserialize the result dynamically 
Here is my code...

```
if (parameters[i].Name == argument2[i].ParameterNameField)
                {
                    using (Stream result = new MemoryStream(argument2[i].ParameterValueField))
                    {
                        pars[i] = Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(parameters[i].ParameterType, result);
                    }
                }
```

parameters[i].ParameterType - Get type of the parameter and Deserialize the same.
Thanks again.
But I getting confused as per your Answer
**"As a side note: in the v1.* builds, the primary API is generic; the non-generic API had to do some extra work (and had some extra overhead). In the v2.* builds, the core codebase is non-generic."**
Is this code take extra overhead ?